# Cockroach or insects triggering conductive ink sensor

Tags: arduino, conductive

I want to modify a cockroach to get it to trigger a conductive ink sensor or Arduino with foil capacitive touch setup.

At the moment there is no reaction as far as I can see (in the serial monitor)

I was wondering about spraying it with water to make it wetter?
Or modifying its feet somehow?
Maybe some little shoes? :)

Alternatively, suggestions of better insects?

Comment: Just use metal cockroaches like everyone else.  Do not make them able to self-replicate, pro tip.

Comment: You want to modify the cockroach? Why not modify the sensor so it works with off-the-shelf cockroaches?

Comment: Please provide part number and electrical datasheet for the cockroach in question.

Comment: Spray it with conductive paint.

Comment: Mutant radioactive cockroaches.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll have much luck with resistive sensing - the chitin shell and legs of an insect will have a very high resistance. Any voltage high enough to give reasonable current is likely to cook the little buggers. Not that that's a bad thing, of course.

By the same token, I'm dubious about the capacitance, as well.

I'd suggest a different approach, such as optical sensing.

Comment: Optical sensors are not allowed :)

Comment: (that would be cheating) :) ... and in fact, ideally ink sensor not foil.

I guess a trailing silver wig to bridge across two ink contact points might work... 

But is conductive ink a resistive touch mechanism then, not capacitive touch? Isn´t resistive touch about force not conductivity?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would try increasing the sensitivity of the capacitive sensor.

Actually increasing the sensitivity of a conductive ink sensor might work too. I would expect insects to have a relatively high resistance, so you'd have to really send a high voltage through the sensor to see a response.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these... maybe with aluminum foil booties.

[image]